# SQLAlchemy Decomposing DateTime Fields

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a model of the form:

```
class MyModel(base):
    # ...
    datetime = Column(DateTime)
    # ...
```

and would like to create a `.date` and a `.time` property which correspond to the `.datetime` column.  The SQLA documentations shows a couple of examples of *combining* properties (such as `firstname + lastname => fullname`) but nothing for decomposing.

I think using `@hybrid_property` and friends I can do the initial decomposition but am unsure about assignment (so if `n = MyModel.query...one()` I wish to be able to do `n.date = d` and have it update the `.datetime` field.)

My primary RDBMS is MySQL.

(For those that are interested in my motivation for wanting to do this: I have a lot of client-side code which is duck-typed to expect `.date` and `.time` fields however many stored procedures and triggers on the server expect a single `.datetime` column.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs say explicitly that you can do this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property), you need to use the `@hybrid.property` and `@value.setter` decorators and your own code to return the date or time in the expected format:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class SomeClass(object):
    @hybrid_property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value
```

Full disclosure: I have used the `property` feature but not the `setter` feature.